# Differentiate 'whinny' and 'nicker' in Spanish

Tags: traducción, animales

I know the Spanish word for whinny (horses' sound) would be 'relincho' but I can't seem to find the correct translation for nicker.

> Definition of nicker according to Google:
>
> 1. (a horse) give a soft breathy whinny. (verb)
> 2. a soft whinnying sound. (noun)

In English these two things evoke very different feelings, a horse might nicker as a greeting or to show he is content, while a whinny is much more urgent, caused by fear or a call to other horses that are out of sight.

Is there a way to translate this difference into Spanish other than just saying **'relincho suave'**? I'm based in Argentina but would be interested in a translation in any dialect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have heard to say about horses (probably among others) that they

- relinchan (neigh)
- bufan (snort)
- **resoplan** (snort / puff / wheeze)

I don't know if those translations ara completely accurate, but a `resoplido` is less intense than a `relincho`, so you may go with that for those "soft whinnying sound" a horse does when it is content.

Comment: I googled that a bit and from what I find 'resoplar' is used in a context of worried/excited snorting. As in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9v1FTHXOr8E) video. I'm looking for is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PavH7RfP4rs) sound.
In the same article it refers to the second sound as 'relincho suave', so that might just be the correct translation :/

Comment: @AkkaVoskuil, there you go then. Even if you are already suggesting that in your own question I encourage you to write that as a formal answer and accept it.

Comment: +1 for "resoplar". That's what I'd use too.